# How to write Ram used to a file from a bash script

Tags: bash, shell

I am wanting to write the amount of ram used to a file in a bash script.

if you run the command `free` you get the following output

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          7930       4103       3826          0         59       2060
-/+ buffers/cache:       1983       5946
Swap:        15487          0      15487
```

I am wanting to pull the used bit out and write to a file something like

`MemUsed: 4103`

I have tried varies of
`cat free | grep used'  uniq >> ramInfo.txt` but have been unable to get it correct.

I am completely new to shell scripts so forgive me if this is relatively simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this and you will get the value:

```
free -h | awk '/^Mem/{print $4}'
```

You can also get the memory free in Kilobytes from `/proc/meminfo`:

```
cat /proc/meminfo | awk -F':' '/MemFree/{print $2}' | sed 's/^ *//g;s/ *$//g'
```

Comment: @John Kugelman, Why did you remove the word **Regards** from the reply in your edit? Just curious to know. Is it out of context?

Comment: The norm on Stack Overflow is to leave out thanks, greetings, signatures, etc. We're a cold and heartless bunch. ;-)